# How may I determine Java version from inside the Chef custom resource without passing it as a parameter?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, chef-custom-resource

I am creating a custom resource and would like to make it as self-contained as possible. I **need to determine java version** that is going to be **available on the node** so I will be able to setup JAVA_OPTS variable properly, depending on Java version. I would **prefer to find** this **out without** making resource's client to **pass** this information **as a parameter**. Could you please suggest me some solutions?

Kind regards,
Denuil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `shell_out!` helper method to run `java -version` and parse the output. You can look at the data in the Ohai languages plugin which does already check some of this for you.

Comment: Thank you very much coderanger. Your answer is really useful to me.